# Modifying PDF files

Tags: command-line, software-rec, editors, gui, pdf

I would like to do some basic editing on existing PDF file. More specifically:

- Add chapters/bookmarks
- Change page numbering

However, I cannot find any tool, GUI or command line, which would offer this functionality. Is there any free-open alternative tools?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) mainly. But here are some others to consider:

[pdfsam (PDF Split and Merge)](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=42): "pdfsam is an open source tool (GPL license) designed to handle pdf files"

[PDF Slicer](https://junrrein.github.io/pdfslicer/): "A simple application to extract, merge, rotate and reorder pages of PDF documents."

[PDFJam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam): "A small collection of shell scripts which provide a simple interface to much of the functionality of the excellent pdfpages PDF file package (by Andreas Matthias) for [pdfLaTeX](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/)." (You can also use pdfLaTeX directly.)

[jPDFTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/): "jPDF Tweak is a Java Swing application that can combine, split, rotate, reorder, watermark, encrypt, sign, and otherwise tweak PDF files."

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org): a vector graphics editor that can both import PDF pages into its native SVG format, and also export as PDF.

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/): Open source ebook management software that can convert PDFs to other formats, and manipulate them in other ways. Comes with command line tools such as [pdfmanipulate](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/cli/pdfmanipulate.html) which can be useful.

[Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) of course can do a lot of things with PDF files too.

Comment: I use pdfjam but it seems none will do the 2 things I explicitly listed.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Edit the question to make it clear what you meant by "chapters". I assumed you just wanted to insert one part of a PDF inside another. But perhaps you mean the pdf bookmarks (i.e., which appear in the side pane for some viewers)? PDFJam might not, but the pdfpages package for PDFLaTeX, along with the LaTeX hyperref package, can handle those. pdfedit should be able to change page numbers. With pdfLaTeX/pdfpages you could clip the bottom of the page and add new ones. BRISS can crop off headers/footers too, but you'd have to add them back with something else.

Comment: Oh, and `mbPDFasm` can apparently also do stuff with bookmarks, but I've never used it: http://thierry.schmit.free.fr/spip/spip.php?article15&lang=en

Comment: Another: `jPDFBookmarks`: http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/2009/03/patch-for-linux-launcher.html

Answer (score 12):

I know two programs for manipulating PDFs under Linux:

[PDEedit](http://pdfedit.petricek.net/en/index.html) "PDFedit is a free open source pdf editor and a library for manipulating PDF documents, released under terms of GNU GPL version 2. It includes PDF manipulating library based on xpdf, GUI, set of command line tools and a pdf editor."

and
[pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) "If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover, hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses. Pdftk is a simple tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents."

Comment: pdfedit: I don't have qt3 and I cannot install it (not in portage) & I cannot get it to compile with qt4 (even with qt3support).

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX with the `pdfpages` and `bookmark` packages can do most of these things.

This works by creating a new `tex` document and including the original PDF documents (or parts of it) via `\includepdf` (see the [pdfpages manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)).

You can also change the page numbering, e.g.

```latex
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
% include pdf pages that should have roman numbering (the front matter)
\pagenumbering{arabic} % switch to arabic numbering
\setcounter{page}{1} % reset page counter
% include pdf pages that should have arabic numbering (the main matter)
```

These "logical" page numbers are merely labels that most PDF readers can use to navigate to a particular page. There's still also the underlying "physical" page numbers running consecutively from 1, for lower-level interactions (see below).

After you've included the existing pdf pages with the correct logical page numbering, you can set PDF bookmarks ("outlines") using the `\bookmark` command. The basic syntax is

```latex
\bookmark[page=<pagenumber>,level=<level>]{<title>}
```

where `<pagenumber>` is the page number of the target page. Note that these are not the "logical" page numbers defined earlier, but the internal page numbers running consecutively from 1, from the beginning of the pdf. Nesting bookmarks is done through specifying `<level>`, where `0` is the top level. The `<title>` is the text to be shown in the PDF reader's outline. See the [bookmark manual](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/bookmark/bookmark.pdf) for details.

Compiling the `tex` file will generate a new PDF with the desired page numbers and bookmarks.

For a complete example of how all of this comes together, see https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/pdf-bookmarks-with-latex.html

Comment: Oh no the link died! I found it in an archive https://web.archive.org/web/20120616001456/https://michaelgoerz.net/blog/2011/04/pdf-bookmarks-with-latex/

Comment: The current link is https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/pdf-bookmarks-with-latex.html

Answer (score 5):

The only way I found to add page numbers to a PDF was with LaTeX:

Create a file /usr/local/bin/add-page-numbers.tex

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\topmargin 70pt
\oddsidemargin 150pt

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\Large\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{input.pdf}
\end{document}
```

And a file /usr/local/bin/pdf-numbers

```
#!/bin/bash
name="${1%\.pdf}-numbers"
wd="$(pwd)"
dir=/tmp/pdf-numbers
mkdir -p "$dir"
cp "$1" "$dir/input.pdf"
cd "$dir"
pdflatex --jobname "$name" /usr/local/bin/add-page-numbers.tex > /dev/null
mv "$name.pdf" "$wd"
rm -r "$dir"
```

Make the latter file executable, and run it with

```
    pdf-numbers example.pdf
```

It will create a pdf file called example-numbers.pdf (and overwrite it if it already exists!).

Comment: Working very well. Imperfection lies in absolute paths, but that's nothing I couldn't manage. However, could you elaborate how did u added these numbers and how change positions of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

pdfimport for openoffice is a good alternative to edit PDF documents and re-export to PDF or save to another format. The imported PDF can be edited with OpenOffice Draw.

Answer (score 0):

*Foxit Pdf Reader for Linux* can be used for adding bookmarks to PDF files.
It has a Navigation Panel for bookmarks where you can add/delete bookmarks.

You can even organize the bookmarks into different containers, like heading 1, heading 1.1, heading 1.1.1, etc.

Note that it adds the bookmarks using a "LIFO queue" concept instead of an "array" concept. So you cannot rearrange the bookmarks using a single mouse drag-and-drop operation, because only the first element in the queue is modifiable. However, you can use multiple drag-and-drop operations (patiently) to move the bookmarks around until you get the order just the way you want it to be.